# iOS App in webview - trick app into thinking page has reloaded

Tags: javascript, ios, dom, ios6

OK,

I have a production iOS app that has a webview.
It listens to the webview for a URL change and throws up a spinner.
Then listens for webview to finishing loading and hides the spinner.

Problem is the webview has been changed to have a hash change to fix the back buttons.  This triggers the above URL change spinner, BUT spinner never goes because a hash change won't reload the page and the load event is never triggered to remove.

Is there anyway with javascript from within the webview to trick the app, maybe by effecting document.readyState...

To fool the app that the page loaded/reloaded and the App removes the Spinner.

Comment: NOT A FIX. But writing an iframe onto the page, the load event of that iframe triggers the webViewDidFinishLoad again.

So a hidden iframe written everytime we navigate via the #hashtag.  Then removes the spinner.

Answer (score 0):

There is one delegate method of the UIWebView

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;

which will calle when your URL stop loading.

Comment: Yes but a #hash change doesn't reload the page, therefore that method isn't fired to remove the spinner.

Ideally the app would be changed to not present the spinner on URL change if it is a #hashtag change... but thats not an issue as it is a production app out in the wild.

Answer (score 0):

We tried a few things;

1. We wrote an image into the page (1x1 gif), and that did not trick a page load event...
2. But then we found writing an iframe into the page, when the iframe loaded (an empty html file), the page load event was triggered again and the native loading overlay was removed.